# Why is there an empty value in input?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

Why is there such a value in input ? On the first render, I set it to the value that is already loaded from the editor. But it is not displayed in the markup, and the value is empty

Here is my code

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (data !== null) {
      const { documents } = data
      setValue('documents.type', data.documents.type);
    }
  }, []);
```

But in the end the meaning is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ziuZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Will need more information to try to help you out.
But since you already destructured documents from data, you could just change the setValue to `setValue(documents.type)`

again, will need more information.

Comment: what information do you need ? Thanks for the help